# How to hide login view and make it only accessible by going to custom url?

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, routes, asp.net-identity

I have a asp.net c# mvc application and I want to hide the login view from users. I only want someone to be able to go to the login view by surfing to /login. I scatfolded Identity and I can't get this to work.

This is my route in Program.cs:

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "login",
                pattern: "/login",
                defaults: new { Area = "identity", Controller = "account", Action = "login" }
            );
```